# very basic question about complex integration over an arc and the connection to residue calculus

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ have a pole of order $N$ at $z=x \in \mathbb{R}$; consider the CCW-oriented arc $$C_{\theta}:=\{z: z-x=\rho e^{i\phi} \ \ with \ 0\leq \phi \leq \theta ; \rho>0\}$$

I want to prove that $$\lim_{\rho \to 0}\int_{C_{\theta}} f(z)dz=i\theta Res_{z=x} f(z)$$

(is it true ?! and if the arc is CW-oriented we have to multiply the right hand side of the above formula by a minus sign )

I tried to prove this by considering the Laurent series of $f(z)$ and parametrising $C_{\theta}$ but I could not convince myself that the above formula is true; then I tried to verify this for a very simple example where $f(z)=\displaystyle \frac{1}{z^2}$ and $\theta=\pi$; so $Res_{z=0}f(z)=0$ and the limit as $\rho \to 0$ of the integral over $C_{\pi}$ must be $0$; but $$\lim_{\rho \to 0}\int_{C_{\pi}} \frac{1}{z^2}dz=\lim_{\rho \to 0}\int^{\pi}_0 \rho^{-2}e^{-2i\theta} \cdot i\rho e^{i\theta}d\theta =\lim_{\rho \to 0} i\rho^{-1} \int^{\pi}_{0} e^{-i\theta}d\theta = \lim_{\rho \to 0} 2\rho^{-1} = \infty $$

Any help is really appreciated, thanks !

Comment: As far as I know this theorem is true for *simple* poles. Check this.

Comment: @Joanpemo Yes, you are right; thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(z)$ can be written as

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-N}^{\infty}a_n(z-x)^n$$

then we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{C_{\theta}} f(z)\,dz&=\lim_{\rho \to 0}\int_0^\theta \sum_{n=-N}^{\infty}a_n(\rho e^{i\phi})^n\,i\rho e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\sum_{n=-N}^{\infty}a_n i\rho^{n+1}\int_0^\theta e^{i(n+1)\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=i\theta a_{-1}+\sum_{n=-N,n\ne -1}^{\infty}a_n \rho^{n+1}\left(\frac{e^{i(n+1)\theta}-1}{n+1}\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

If $\theta=2\pi$, then the all the terms in the series vanish and we have

$$\int_{C_{2\pi}}f(z)\,dz=i2\pi a_{-1}$$

as expected.  If $\theta<2\pi$, then the limit as $\rho\to 0$ of the series diverges.

Comment: Thanks ! 
If $N=1$; i.e. if $f(z)$ has a simple pole at $x$, the formula  $$\lim_{\rho \to 0}\int_{C_{\theta}} f(z)dz=i\theta Res_{z=x} f(z)$$  is true for all $\theta$.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And you're correct.  If the pole is simple, then the relationship holds.